# CSS Animation/sprite sheet won't stay on last image

Tags: html, css, css-animations, css-sprites

I have the below code

```css
div.sprite {
  width: 200px;
  height: 194px;
  background-image: url("https://www.giftofspeed.com/sprite-generator/sprites/8a7a791467c5d7a9eb8050cdd3dee4fa.png");
  animation: play 1s steps(5) 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes play {
  from {
    background-position-x: -0px;
  }
  to {
    background-position-x: -974px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="sprite">

</div>
```

The issue is I can't get it to stop on the last frame (5) (also the animation seems to be a little off)

It keeps going back to the first, i've googled it and found loads of others have the same issue, but changing steps from 5 to 4, or setting

```
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
```

which seem to be the suggested fixes are not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should correct the last value of background-position. Your image has a width of `974px` so using `-974px` is equivalent to `0px` since there is the repeat so it will start again on the first one. You need to decrease it and then use `steps(4)`. You may also correct the `width` of the div for a more accurate result:

```css
div.sprite {
  width: 194.8px; /* (974/5) */
  height: 194px;
  background-image: url("https://www.giftofspeed.com/sprite-generator/sprites/8a7a791467c5d7a9eb8050cdd3dee4fa.png");
  animation: play 1s steps(4) forwards;
}

@keyframes play {
  from {
    background-position-x: -0px;
  }
  to {
    background-position-x: -779.2px; /*974 - (974/5)*/
  }
}

img {
 border:1px solid;
 background:repeating-linear-gradient(to right,transparent 0px,transparent calc(100%/5 - 2px),#000 calc(100%/5 - 2px),#000 calc(100%/5));
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.giftofspeed.com/sprite-generator/sprites/8a7a791467c5d7a9eb8050cdd3dee4fa.png" height=50>
<div class="sprite"></div>
```